# Repetir codigo para o mesmo grupo de produtos

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho uma planilha com milhares de produtos conforme o exemplo abaixo, onde o codigo so consta no tipo de servico(coluna esquerda), e eu quero que conste em todos os produtos de um mesmo tipo(coluna direita). Na pratica, quero que o 'codigo 1' seja arrastado ate o codigo 2, e este ate o codigo 3, e assim sucessivamente. Existe algo pronto no pandas pra isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)

while('' in df['CODIGO'].values):

    df.loc[df['CODIGO'] == '', 'CODIGO'] = df.loc[:, 'CODIGO'].shift(1)
```

Comment: Essa solucao nao vai ter utilidade, pois sao milhares de elementos que estao dispostos dessa forma(um em cima do outro), e eu nao tenho condicoes de olhar um a um pra saber quantos codigos tem e aplicar essa solucao. Minha planilha foi exemplificativa. Eu quero que, sempre que a coluna codigo apresentar algum valor, esse valor seja repetido ate encontrar o proximo, exatamente como esta na coluna da direita. Uma outra coisa: eu exemplifiquei com codigo 1, 2 e 3. Mas pode ser que a coluna contenha codigo 11, depois codigo 9, ou seja, nao e sequencial.

Comment: A segunda parte da minha solução é geral

Comment: Blz. Tentei executar e dar essa mensagem: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Comment: Como fica o DataFrame depois que você executa? E como está o DataFrame antes que você executa? Para poder te ajudar preciso ver o DataFrame de verdade (ou pelo menos parte dele); não uma foto de uma planilha no Excel.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta original e inseri o dataframe nela. Fica assim apos executar o comando que voce sugeriu.

Comment: Obrigado! E antes de executar?

Comment: Amigo, o seu codigo nao faz nada, a nao ser retornar aquela mensagem de erro que lhe passei. Antes e apos executar o seu codigo, o dataframe fica exatamente como esta, sem nenhuma alteracao

Comment: É mais importante para mim ver como está o DataFrame antes de você executar. No caso, se você está dizendo que fica da maneira que você mostrou. Então você precisa fazer algumas alterações antes. Vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: O df antes de eu executar o comando(assim que eu importo para o pandas), esta do jeito que postei, e depois tambem. Ou seja, nao ha mudanca alguma.

Comment: Vê se agora vai

Comment: Maravilha, funcionou. E' isso mesmo que preciso. Muito obrigado.